# Button array in Fragment

Tags: android, arrays, android-fragments

I am new to Android Programming. I want to add an array of buttons fragment layout dynamically.

Activity:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_dir,
                    container, false);

            LinearLayout linearLayout=new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            LayoutParams param=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(param);
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            LayoutParams param2=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            Button dirButton[]=new Button[5];

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                dirButton[i].setLayoutParams(param2);
                linearLayout.addView(dirButton[i]);
            }


            ViewGroup vg=(ViewGroup)rootView;
            vg.addView(linearLayout);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

But this is causing Null pointer exception. But if only one button is used then it works like:

```
Button dirButton=new Button(getActivity());
```

Is there way to achieve the button array?

Comment: Can you use an `ArrayList` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays don't work like that. Try something like this:

```
Button[] buttonArray = new Button[5]; 
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    buttonArray[i] = new Button(getActivity());
    buttonArray[i].setLayoutParams(params);
    linearLayout.addView(buttonArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = PlaceholderFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    public PlaceholderFragment() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my, container, false);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(param);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams param2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        Button dirButton[] = new Button[5];

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            dirButton[i] = new Button(getActivity());
            dirButton[i].setLayoutParams(param2);
            linearLayout.addView(dirButton[i]);
        }


        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) rootView;
        vg.addView(linearLayout);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

When you have an array of objects, the default value is **null** . You forgot to actually create the Button. Here is the part you needed to change :

```
dirButton[i] = new Button(getActivity());
dirButton[i].setLayoutParams(param2);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, the definition of the `Button[]` is wrong.

Comment: The code works, you might be missing some imports,here is the full project, just open it in Android Studio and run it https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9075482/Demo.zip

Comment: @XaverKapeller what is wrong with my code, you said it doesn't compile when it does and voted me down, why?